# How can I resolve this error: packages have unmet dependencies: linux-image-oem-20.04b: Depends?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I am getting this error

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  linux-image-oem-20.04b : Depends:
 linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried almost everything and it is not letting me install,remove or update anything.I have also tried manually installing linux-image package but it throws me this error ->

```
 dpkg: error processing archive
 linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb (--install): 
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-1049-oem.dpkg-new': Operation not
 permitted Errors were encountered while processing: 

 linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb
```

I tried updating the whole system too but it gives me this error

```
 Transaction failed: The package system is broken  The following
 packages have unmet dependencies: linux-image-oem-20.04b: Depends:
 linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem but it is not installed
```

Tried installing the OEM kernel using the below command:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem
```

and it gives this error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem (5.10.0-1049.51) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-1049-oem.dpkg-new': Operation not permitte
d
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem_5.10.0-1049.51_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does `sudo dpkg -P linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem` work?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa-charmander X74)

Comment: @mikewhatever it says "dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem which isn't installed" after running your command

Comment: 20.04.2 shows you are behind in upgrades.  After you can do upgrades you need to fix that.

Comment: @David upgrade isn't working

Comment: Try to install the OEM kernel: `sudo apt install linux-image-5.10.0-1049-oem`. It will likely fail, and we need to see that error output. Add it to your Question above. An effective way to solve dependency conflicts is to follow the chain until apt tells you exactly which package conflicts and why. Once you resolve THAT conflict, it all works properly again.

Comment: @user535733 updated my question.

Comment: So your actual problem is not "unmet dependencies". Your actual problem seems to apt: `unable to open '/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-1049-oem.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted`. Interesting. That's a permission issue, not a package conflict. Are you the admin on this system? Is this a pre-installed new-hardware system (hence the OEM kernel)? Or is there anything unusual or complex about it, like a VM or container or WSL or older hardware or you installed it on the hardware yourself?

Comment: @user535733  Unable to open just because there isn't any file like that in boot folder.

Comment: @user535733 Though there are 3 files with the same name but having different versions:
1) vmlinuz-5.10.0-1014-oem
2) vmlinuz-5.10.0-1045-oem
3) vmlinuz

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of an Anti-Virus utility that is not allowing `apt` to access the `/boot` directory. Disable any anti-virus services you are using.

For example, if you're using MacCaffe, run the following commands to fix it (The commands will remove the antivirus utility):

```
sudo dpkg --purge mfedx 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeetp 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespaac 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeespfileaccess 
Sudo dpkg --purge mcafeeesp 
sudo dpkg --purge mcafeert 
sudo dpkg --purge mfecma 
sudo dpkg --purge mfert
```